# Android onclick event?

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm officially going crazy as to why this is not working properly.  I have tried pretty much everything but it's not calling the onclick event properly?

This is my error message that I am getting after the = sign

```
The type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must implement the
inherited abstract method
DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int)
```

and  keeps telling me to add unimplemented items. But I thought it was implemented with the `View v`?

Can anyone help me understand as to why this is not working properly?

Even if I implement the onclick listener in the beginning it's still not working? I'm so confused?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/eraserBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_tool_bg"
    android:src="@drawable/eraser" />


            mEraserBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eraserBtn);

             mEraserBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int nBtnID = mEraserBtn.getId();
                    // If the mode is not changed, open the setting view. If the mode is same, close the setting view. 
                    if(nBtnID == mEraserBtn.getId()){
                        if(mSCanvas.getCanvasMode()==SCanvasConstants.SCANVAS_MODE_INPUT_ERASER){
                            mSCanvas.toggleShowSettingView(SCanvasConstants.SCANVAS_SETTINGVIEW_ERASER);
                        }
                        else{
                            mSCanvas.setCanvasMode(SCanvasConstants.SCANVAS_MODE_INPUT_ERASER);
                            mSCanvas.showSettingView(SCanvasConstants.SCANVAS_SETTINGVIEW_ERASER, false);
                        }
                    }   
                }
                });
```

Comment: Aswer your own question for future reference and if other people run into the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must implement the
>   inherited abstract method
>   DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int)

You have imported incorrect `OnClickListener`. Your import has to be

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

and not

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

Both have same name(easy to make a mistake) but they are different. Be careful.

Comment: Thanks I know there was something wrong just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @RichTalcik you are welcome. If answer works so for other developers accept answer as working one :) thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have another ClickListener for Dialog in your application, or you're importing the wrong ClickListener, try to do that and test if is it:

```
         mEraserBtn.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener){
```

If it works, you need to organize your imports as mentioned before